# HTML Signature issue with style in outlook

Tags: html, css

I cannot get my html signature to show up correctly in outlook. The spacing is all off, as if the style that I just put inline doesn't work...what am I missing? Please help!!

here is what it looks like in outlook vs what it looks like in a browser:

[Wrong signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DNsn.png)

[Correct signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOhC5.png)

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Dan Broyles Signature</title>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: relative; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 831px; height: 305px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;">
        <div style="left: -2px; top: -2px; position: absolute; width: 834px; height: 308px; z-index: 1;"><img src="images/Base.png"></div>
        <div style="left: 0px; top: -1px; position: absolute; width: 188px; height: 307px; z-index: 2;"><img src="images/placeholder.png"></div>
        <div style="left: 318px; top: 242px; position: absolute; width: 18px; height: 26px; z-index: 3;"><img src="images/location.png"></div>
        <div style="left: 357px; top: 252px; position: absolute; width: 445px; height: 19px; z-index: 4;"><img src="images/Mailingaddress.png"></div>
        <div style="left: 654px; top: 34px; position: absolute; width: 147px; height: 69px; z-index: 5;"><img src="images/Layer7.png"></div>
        <div style="left: 566px; top: 163px; position: absolute; width: 138px; height: 15px; z-index: 7;"><img src="images/fax.png"></div>
        <div style="left: 519px; top: 156px; position: absolute; width: 28px; height: 24px; z-index: 8;"><img src="images/printer.png"></div>
        <div style="left: 313px; top: 199px; position: absolute; width: 28px; height: 23px; z-index: 9;"><img src="images/mail.png"></div>
        <div style="left: 359px; top: 205px; position: absolute; width: 346px; height: 20px; z-index: 10;">
            <a href="mailto:dan.broyles@ashbrokerage.com"><img src="images/emailaddress.png"> </a>
        </div>
        <div style="left: 314px; top: 151px; position: absolute; width: 26px; height: 25px; z-index: 11;"><img src="images/mobile.png"></div>
        <div style="left: 360px; top: 161px; position: absolute; width: 138px; height: 15px; z-index: 12;">
            <a href="tel:12604696853"><img src="images/TelNumbercopy.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div style="left: 314px; top: 82px; position: absolute; width: 206px; height: 12px; z-index: 13;"><img src="images/Designation.png"></div>
        <div style="left: 314px; top: 34px; position: absolute; width: 298px; height: 31px; z-index: 14;"><img src="images/Name.png"></div>
        <div style="left: 186px; top: 226px; position: absolute; width: 81px; height: 80px; z-index: 15;"><img src="images/Base_0.png"></div>
        <div style="left: 186px; top: 151px; position: absolute; width: 80px; height: 79px; z-index: 16;"><img src="images/Base_1.png"></div>
        <div style="left: 186px; top: -1px; position: absolute; width: 81px; height: 79px; z-index: 18;"><img src="images/Basecopy.png"></div>
        <div style="left: 186px; top: 74px; position: absolute; width: 80px; height: 80px; z-index: 19;"><img src="images/Base_2.png"></div>
        <div style="left: 203px; top: 172px; position: absolute; width: 47px; height: 38px; z-index: 17;">
            <a href="http://www.twitter.com/AshBrokerage" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div style="left: 203px; top: 92px; position: absolute; width: 47px; height: 47px; z-index: 20;">
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/broylesdan" target="_blank"><img src="images/linkedin.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div style="left: 215px; top: 14px; position: absolute; width: 24px; height: 48px; z-index: 21;">
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/AshBrokerageCorp" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
            <a></a>
        </div>
        <div style="left: 195px; top: 238px; position: absolute; width: 61px; height: 58px; z-index: 22;">
            <a href="http://www.AshBrokerage.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Layer5.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: div based design doesn't support by outlook properly

Comment: You should use tables to ensure consistency throughout all clients.